# Vite is probably changing my import path. What should I do?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, vite

I keep getting this error when I'm running my front-end server (5173, vite) , and my backend server which is synchronized with my front.
This is how I import my file in one my my reducers in reducer:

```
import { toyService } from "./../../services/toy.service.js"
```

It is the right path.
Whenever I'm running both of my servers, my browser shows me this: 'Uncaught

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'toyService' before initialization
    at toy.reducer.js:24:15'
```

(A line using a function from toyService).
The same happens with the other reducer although the import path is correct.
I have not modified any detail in the configuration Vite file and it used to work just fine.
When I looked at how my browser is trying to reach this file using the Sources at the devtools, I saw this:

```
'import { toyService } from "/src/services/toy.service.js"
```

Does anybody have any idea what would cause such error?
It is worth mentioning I use MongoDB to get at modify data at the backend.

So far I have consulted with friends, ChatGPT, tried to find anything about such error on Google.. nothing.

Comment: Hello have you tried deleting your cache yet (`rm -rf node_modules/.vite` ) ? If you've updated toyService, it may not have taken this into account.